# Помогите отправить пост запрос с куками и дата Javascript Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Помогите отправить пост запрос на сайт, поставил модуль request, он прекрасно работает если делать запросы без header, но мне надо отправить запрос с моими куками. выдает ошибку csrf "message":"CSRF check failed.","params":"user-id...........(тут он пишет всю дату(data)
Я так понял, он не видит мои куки, как их включить в request, не смог разобраться в jar()

```
 function sendpostRequest() {


var cookie = 'PHPSESSID=111111; csrf=1111111; user-id=111111; stack[hash]=111111; stack[user]=11111111;';

    let data = 'user-id=111111&csrf=11111&currencies%5Bmetal%5D=1&currencies%5Bkeys%5D=1';

var options = {
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Cookie: 'PHPSESSID=1111; csrf=11111; user-id=11111; stack[hash]=1111; stack[user]=1111;'
    },
    body: data

};

function callback(error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
    else{
        console.log(error);
        console.log(body);
    }
}
 // j = request.jar()
//request = request.defaults({jar:j})
request(options, callback);
  }
```

Comment: Всё он видит. А вот токен ты ему неверный шлёшь. [CSRF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межсайтовая_подделка_запроса).

Comment: я проверял запрос через курл и через модуль axios, там все нормально отправляется, но там есть минусы курл в яве не оч юзать а axios работает криво. хотелось бы через request сделать и чтоб все работало

Comment: Бери фиддлер и сравнивай запросы.

Comment: фидлер не пашет че то у меня на маке) моно выдает ошибку.